# Android notificationlight not working

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm using a notification to let the user now that the service is still running. Now I'd like to use the notificationlight to remind the user. (because it's fancy)

The notification works fine, but the notification light does nothing. Other applications work fine with the notification light, (gtalk, facebook)

it's more or less the example code for notifications with addition of these flags:

```
notification.ledARGB = 0xff00ff00;
notification.ledOnMS = 100;
notification.ledOffMS = 100;
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;

notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR + Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

and

```
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
```

instead doesn't work either.

I'm debugging on a Galaxy Nexus with Android 4.0, but the app's target is Android 2.3.3

EDIT:
could this be a problem of permission? If yes, which one? I looked through all and found no matching permission for the notification light.

Comment: Obligatory "are you sure you have correct permissions for the notification lights"

Comment: good question, were do I get them?

Comment: still not working... the documentation doesn't list any needed permissions for the light

Comment: My mistake -- you don't need permissions for this.  I would try setting ARGB to ffffffff and see if that makes a difference

Comment: tried it just now, no change.

Comment: try to increase ledOnMS to ~3000

Comment: @Athmos : I have been facing teh same problem with notification lights. The lights don't show up on receiving a new notification for my app. Is it working now for you. Please do answer your own question if you get the solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is an error with the + operator, you need the OR:

```
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
```

EDIT: and if you are using flags, I think the right one should be:

```
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS
```

Comment: It's not an error, it's a feature! Those are Bits to set, the plus works fine. Since each flag is another bit, you will never get a carry over. But the OR would work just fine. FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS is set, as you see in the upper codeblock, according to the documentation it's not needed if you use the DEFAULT_LIGHTS flag.

Answer (score 2):

On jelly bean devices, led only works if notification priority is set to max or default, please check again. Following snippet of code is working fine for me  on jb devices.

```
notification.setLights(0xFF0000FF,100,3000);
notification.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
```

Here I'm showing blue color led for notification which will remain on for 100 ms and off for 3000 ms till user unlocks his device.

And check if you are using NotificationCompat (compatibility) class than ignore setDefaults method and use SetLight, SetSound, Setvibration, etc